# How do I get the collection of Model State Errors in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation, spark-view-engine

How do I get the collection of errors in a view?

I don't want to use the Html Helper Validation Summary or Validation Message. Instead I want to check for errors and if any display them in specific format. Also on the input controls I want to check for a specific property error and add a class to the input.

P.S. I'm using the Spark View Engine but the idea should be the same.

So I figured I could do something like...

```
<if condition="${ModelState.Errors.Count > 0}">
  DisplayErrorSummary()
</if>

....and also...

<input type="text" value="${Model.Name}" 
       class="?{ModelState.Errors["Name"] != string.empty} error" />

....
```

Or something like that.

**UPDATE**

My final solution looked like this:

```
<input type="text" value="${ViewData.Model.Name}" 
       class="text error?{!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && 
                           ViewData.ModelState["Name"].Errors.Count() > 0}" 
       id="Name" name="Name" />
```

This only adds the error css class if this property has an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all Errors from ASP.Net MVC modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
<% ViewData.ModelState.IsValid %>
```

or

```
<% ViewData.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1) %>
```

and for a specific property...

```
<% ViewData.ModelState["Property"].Errors %> // Note this returns a collection
```

Comment: the ModelState property is of dictionary type
to get the error for pass the key name

ViewData.ModelState["Name"]

Comment: regarding "ViewData.ModelState["Property"].Errors"
would this throw a null reference exception if there was no key with the name "Property"?
would it be better to first check for null on the ViewData.ModelState["Property"] prior to reading in Errors?

Comment: @DaveH Yep, you should totally check for existence first

Answer (score 65):

To just get the errors from the ModelState, use this Linq:

```
var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
```

Comment: would this throw a null reference exception if there was no key with the specified name?
would it be better to first check for null on the ViewData.ModelState[key] prior to reading in Errors?

Comment: Because we start by iterating over this.ModelState.Keys, I don't see the potential for a KeyNotFoundException. I think that check would be overkill.

Answer (score 31):

Condensed version of [@ChrisMcKenzie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3459569/62600):

```
var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors);
```

Answer (score 30):

This will give you one string with all the errors with comma separating

```
string validationErrors = string.Join(",",
                    ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
                    .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
                    .ToArray());
```

Comment: This is the only thing I found in this entire list that actually prints out the errors! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Putting together several answers from above, this is what I ended up using:

```
var validationErrors = ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
    .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
    .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
    .ToList();
```

`validationErrors` ends up being a `List<string>` that contains each error message. From there, it's easy to do what you want with that list.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Chad!  To show all the errors associated with the key, here's what I came up with.  For some reason the base Html.ValidationMessage helper only shows the first error associated with the key.

```
    <%= Html.ShowAllErrors(mykey) %>
```

HtmlHelper:

```
    public static String ShowAllErrors(this HtmlHelper helper, String key) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[key] != null) {
            foreach (var e in helper.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors) {
                TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
                div.MergeAttribute("class", "field-validation-error");
                div.SetInnerText(e.ErrorMessage);
                sb.Append(div.ToString());
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VB.

```
Dim validationErrors As String = String.Join(",", ModelState.Values.Where(Function(E) E.Errors.Count > 0).SelectMany(Function(E) E.Errors).[Select](Function(E) E.ErrorMessage).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what property caused the error, you can, using reflection, loop over all properties:

```
public static String ShowAllErrors<T>(this HtmlHelper helper) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Type myType = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] propInfo = myType.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propInfo) {
        foreach (var e in helper.ViewData.ModelState[prop.Name].Errors) {
            TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
            div.MergeAttribute("class", "field-validation-error");
            div.SetInnerText(e.ErrorMessage);
            sb.Append(div.ToString());
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Where T is the type of your "ViewModel".

Answer (score 0):

Got this from BrockAllen's answer that worked for me, it displays the keys that have errors:

```
    var errors =
    from item in ModelState
    where item.Value.Errors.Count > 0
    select item.Key;
    var keys = errors.ToArray();
```

Source: [https://forums.asp.net/t/1805163.aspx?Get+the+Key+value+of+the+Model+error](https://forums.asp.net/t/1805163.aspx?Get%20the%20Key%20value%20of%20the%20Model%20error)