# C# how to join a list with delim, e.g., List<string> strList;, then strList.Join(",")

Tags: c#

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
strList.Add("a");
strList.Add("b");
// I want to do this: string joined = strList.Join(",");
// joined = "a,b"
```

Do I need to make an extension off of List or something like that? I suppose it could first check to see that the type is string, vs trying to concatenate a Book object, if I had List bookList

Thanks!

--- EDIT

To clarify, I was asking for an extension for `List<string>`.  sorry for the confusion!

Comment: can you give examples for book object and other one , you are mentioning as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to write a custom extension like this:

```
public static string JoinString
    (this IEnumerable<string> source, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, source);
}
```

This would allow you to call `JoinString` on anything that implements `IEnumerable<string>` (like `List<string>` for instance):

```
string joined = strList.JoinString(",");
```

Please note that this is a .NET 4 specific answer - if you are using .NET 3.5 then the extension method would have to look like this:

```
public static string JoinString
    (this IEnumerable<string> source, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, source.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: In .NET 4 overloads were added that accept `IEnumerable<string>`, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx

Comment: String.Join accepts an IEnumerable<string>:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>(); 
strList.Add("a"); 
strList.Add("b"); 
string joined = string.Join(",", strList);
```

String.Join takes an IEnumerable so no need to write special extension method or converting to array via ToArray().

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.  They want to have a `Join` method on the list itself.

Comment: I said "no need to write special extension method", but looking back at question and request to be able to write strList.Join, an extension method is required to add the Join capability to the List.  However, to get the List joined, you can still use String.Join and pass it the List.

Comment: I didn't read it very carefully but I initially took it to mean "Given a List<string>, how to I join its values to make one string" implying maybe he didn't know about passing an IEnumerable<string> to Join.  You are right though, it does seem that he at least wants to know about a Join extension method on List (or IEnumerable) as well as, maybe, applying string.Join to an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to join you can use this code

```
    string line = string.Join(",", strList.ToArray());
 Console.WriteLine(line);
```

and you need to give example of your book and string object, if you want a condition