# Access the error message in ModelState error dictionary in ASP.net MVC unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, modelstate

I have added a key-value pair in the action result like this:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
        public ActionResult ListFacilities(int countryid)
{
...
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error","No facilities reported in this country!");
...
}
```

I have some cumbersome codes like these in a unit test to :

```
 public void ShowFailforFacilities()
 {
    //bogus data
    var facilities = controller.ListFacilities(1) as PartialViewResult;


    Assert.AreSame("No facilities reported in this country!",
        facilities.ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);

 }
```

Of course, it works whenever I have only one error.
I don't like `facilities.ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage`.

Is there an easier way for me to fetch the value from that dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your FirstOrDefault isn't needed, because you'll get a NullReferenceException when accessing ErrorMessage. You can just use First().

Either way, I couldn't find any built-in solution. What I've done instead is create an extension method:

```
public static class ExtMethod
    {
        public static string GetErrorMessageForKey(this ModelStateDictionary dictionary, string key)
        {
            return dictionary[key].Errors.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Which works like this:

```
ModelState.GetErrorMessageForKey("error");
```

If you need better exception handling, or support for multiple errors, its easy to extend...

If you want this to be shorter you can create an extension method for the ViewData...

```
public static class ExtMethod
    {
        public static string GetModelStateError(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, string key)
        {
            return viewData.ModelState[key].Errors.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

and usage:

```
ViewData.GetModelStateError("error");
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580944/get-all-modelstate-errors-on-view

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
// Note: In this example, "Error" is the name of your model property.
facilities.ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Value
facilities.ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Error
```