# Displaying model state errors after ajax call on Razor views

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have razor view with @Html.ValidationMessageFor helpers and jquery unobtrusive validation setup.

I want to call controller/action and to show eventual model state errors returned by action by using same validation logic that is already set in place.

I've made some code that does it but I was wondering if there is already way to do it automatically, i.e. if I capture HTTP Bad Request as AJAX response, I want to take out model state errors from response body and plug them in to unobtrusive validation.

I'm looking for complete recommended solution, not workarounds :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can return errors with `Json` result ([How to get all Errors from asp.net mvc modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)):

```
var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

Then manually show errors. Get form validator:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();
```

Then check that your fields are initialized correctly, for example you can look here (optional step):

```
validator.settings.rules
```

OR

```
validator.settings.messages
```

If everything is fine, then you could show error:

```
validator.showErrors({"Password": "Too simple!"});
```

Where `Password` is field name and `Too simple!` is error message.