# ModelState.IsValid false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a form of the Grille Table: when adding a new object in my form :my **modelState.isValid** is set to false. i tried to identify the error by adding this method:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));
    // Breakpoint, Log or examine the list with Exceptions.
}
```

and the error message was just **"*"** i didn't know how to fix it and exactly in which folder i must search my error ??

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934712/961526 (and following answer if you want the error message)

Comment: Check any Model validations are failing i.e DataAnnotations like Required/Range

Comment: @malkam i check DataAnnotations and i fixed my attribute which was with a incorrect required annotation,thanks my **modelsatate.isvalid** is true now.even i fixed my modelstate problem now i have an INTERCEPTION DE CONSTARINTEXCEPTION when to save my form after adding a new object what is this exception? when i put a brikpoint i found that the object i have added is null why is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your break point on line 125 do a Quick Watch on ModelState and go through the Values to find which one(s) have the error flag set.

Link from raphael will help.

Comment: i have done that and i found the error by going through the values @SkyBlues87 thanks