# How to find the exceptions / errors when TryUpdateModel fails to update model in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
if (!TryUpdateModel<Event>(evt))
{ 
   // ... I need to retrieve the errors here
}
```

Sometimes, `TryUpdateModel` fails to update model. I am not able to find reason and exception?

Comment: put try catch to see exception

Comment: I have put code in try catch but when I debug if TryUpdateModel method fails even then it dont moves to catch part

Comment: TryUpdateModel returns a bool

Comment: You will have to use your debugger to inspect the contents of your request in order to figure out what is going on. We can't tell with the information you have provided.

Comment: Is there any way to find out reason why TryUpdateModel fails

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the other `TryXXX` paradigm methods (e.g. `TryParse`), the [`TryUpdateModel` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460189(v=vs.118).aspx) returns a bool indicating whether the model was updated successfully or not.

`TryUpdateModel` updates the `ModelState` dictionary with a list of errors. If `TryUpdateModel` fails (as per the bool return), you can [iterate these as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353107/314291):

```
 var model = new ViewModel();
 var isSuccess = TryUpdateModel(model);

 if (!isSuccess)
 {
     foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
     {
        foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }
     }
 }
```

Otherwise, if you want a hard exception, then use [`UpdateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.updatemodel.aspx) instead.