# Why does the Visual Studio 2013 debugger fail to render string contents after using the StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The Visual Studio 2013 debugger is behaving in an unexpected way after applying .ToString() to a StringBuilder.  In the controller, I'm attempting to intercept some errors, and have adapted some code from this SO post.
[How to get all Errors from ASP.Net MVC modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)

But when the debugger runs, and after a .ToString() action is applied to the StringBuilder, I'm unable to inspect the contents of the string via Watch or hovering over the string.

```
string theErrors = string.Empty;
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", error.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    theErrors = sb.ToString();
    sb = null;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint after this code, and try to inspect the "theErrors" string, Visual Studio debugger displays this message.

> "The name 'theErrors' does not exist in the current context."

This is unexpected behavior.  Am I doing something wrong with the StringBuilder?  I use StringBuilder frequently, and haven't seen this before.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What build configuration are you using?  Are you using `tblErrors` anywhere after this code?

Comment: Thanks Jason. Don't know if I'm following your question.  I intend to use that variable later int the code.  For my sanity, I replaced the StringBuilder with a string and just started concatenating to it. And *that* does capture the error.  I can run with that workaround, but it's annoying StringBuilder isn't working as expected.

Comment: I mean is your configuration set to 'release' or 'debug'.  In a 'release' build the compiler will optimize out unused variables.

Comment: The error isn't about the `StringBuilder`, that would be `The name "sb" does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: Ah, that's it!  Configuration was set to release.  And that had slipped my mind. Switching to Debug corrected this. Thanks Jason.  Please post that as an answer so I can award that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build configuration is set to 'release'.

[image]

The 'Optimize Code' option is enabled by default in the 'Release' configuration.

[image]

Code optimization will optimize out any unused variables.  Changing your build configuration to 'Debug' will stop this.