# How to access all model errors in action filter attributes for asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, action

```
public sealed class MyModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToList();;
        }
        else
        {
            if (next != null)
            {
               await next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This only returns a single error even though my model has multiple errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all Errors from ASP.Net MVC modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)

Comment: What is the value of `context.ModelState.MaxAllowedErrors`?

Comment: This only returns the default number of errors allowed, it returns 200. I wanted to get the list of errors that have occurred e.g my model has two fields with invalid data, I would like those fields returned in the error list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `context.Result` to display the error list:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
    }
    else
    {
        if (next != null)
        {
            await next();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to add the attribute to your controller:

```
[MyModel]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Test tests)
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

Result:
[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters

Comment: Hi Rena, Thanks for your response. I've tested this and it works with  .net core 2.2 but not .net core 3.1. With .net core 3.1 errors list is always empty. Another thing is that my payload is xml and not json

Comment: Hi gee,I also test the code on my asp.net core 3.1 project,it could get the errors successfully.I suggest that you could provide more details(e.g. what is your Startup.cs?).Besides,your payload is xml,how do you make it work?