# ModelState.IsValid keeps coming back as false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

SO I have a view where a member enters the PIN associated with them to clock in

```
@model Models.Member
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1 style="margin-top: 0px;">Club Members Login Below!</h1> @*add this to the style for better ipad title -> "text-align: center;"*@
</br>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClubHours", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.PIN)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.PIN)<br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.PIN)<br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ClockIn" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ClockOut" />
}
```

which interacts with this action result:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClubHours(string submit, Member member)//member clocking in
{
    if (submit.Equals("ClockIn"))
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //validating events fields
        {
            return View("UserLogin");
        }
        else
        {
            var mem = _context.Members.SingleOrDefault(c => c.PIN == member.PIN);
            var hours = new MemberClubHours();
            hours.ClockIn = DateTime.Now;
            mem.Hours.Add(hours);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return View("ClockIn");
        }
    }
    else if (submit.Equals("ClockOut"))
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //validating events fields
        {
            return View("UserLogin");
        }
        else
        {
            var mem = _context.Members.SingleOrDefault(c => c.PIN == member.PIN);
            var hours = new MemberClubHours();
            hours.ClockOut = DateTime.Now;
            mem.Hours.Add(hours);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return View("ClockOut");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View("UserLogin","Login");
    }
}
```

and lastly here is that Member class

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN must be 4 numbers long"), MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN must be 4 numbers long")]
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MemberClubHours> Hours { get; } = new HashSet<MemberClubHours>();
}
```

and the memberclubhours class

```
public class MemberClubHours
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClockIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClockOut { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

The code works correctly and will track the hours of a member, however I'm trying to implement validation, but even if I enter a PIN that is associated with a member in the system, it comes back as not valid? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Print `ValidationSummary` too.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate) to find the model error.

Answer (score 1):

You're validating the model sent from the frontend. Not to the database, are you sure the model is populated according to your Data Annotations in the model?

Check out [ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#model-state) it's asp.net core 3.1 but still relevant

Answer (score 1):

Member model is coming out as invalid because the member Model requires the **Id, PIN, FirstName, LastName** fields.

You can't validate this class with `ModelState.IsValid` because it will check all the properties-- **and it looks like you're only passing the PIN property.**

If you don't want to make a viewModel for it, you could just include those properties as hidden inputfields;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClubHours", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.FirstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.LastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.PIN)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.PIN)<br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.PIN)<br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ClockIn" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ClockOut" />
}
```

Comment: ahhhhh thats right! I should've known that, thanks!