# ASP.Net Core: How do you get the key of an invalid ModelState value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, modelstate

II have an "Edit" page in my .Net 5./ASP.Net MVC app. If `ModelState.IsValid` is "false", I want to check the individual errors before rejecting the entire page.

**PROBLEM**: How do I get the "name" of an invalid item in the `ModelState` list?

For example:

- handler method: `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()`
- `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`: "false"

  this.ModelState.Values[0]: SubKey={ID}, Key="ID", ValidationState=Invalid Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary.ModelStateNode}

**Code:**

```
foreach (ModelStateEntry item in ModelState.Values)
{
    if (item.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)
    {
        // I want to take some action if the invalid entry contains the string "ID"
        var name = item.Key;  // CS1061: 'ModelStateEntry 'does not contain a definition for 'Key'
        ...
```

**QUESTION**: how do I read the "Key" from each invalid ModelState "Values" item???

---

**RESOLUTION**

My basic problem was iterating through "ModelState.Values". Instead, I needed to iterate through "ModelState.Keys" in order to get all the required information.

SOLUTION 1)

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelStateEntry> modelStateDD in ModelState) 
{
    string key = modelStateDD.Key;
    ModelStateEntry item = ModelState[key];
    if (item.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid) {
        // Take some action, depending on the key
        if (key.Contains("ID"))
           ...
```

SOLUTION 2)

```
var errors = ModelState
               .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
               .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
               .ToList();
foreach (var error in errors) {
    if (error.Key.Contains("ID"))
       continue;
    else if (error.Key.Contains("Foo"))
      ...
```

Many thanks to devlin carnate for pointing me in the right direction, and to PippoZucca for a great solution!

Comment: Does the selected answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate) answer your question?  (see the comments for that selected answer, too, because someone states how to get the "key")

Comment: @devlin carnate: Thank you for your reply.  I looked at the solutions in that link.  Unfortunately, the only things they retrieve are the error messages.  I want to know the name of the model object that caused the error.  That's the part I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all Errors from ASP.Net MVC modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)

Comment: @FoggyDay : so you tried the solution in the comment?  The comment posted by "viggity".  It specifically states it shows the errors by key...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While debugging, you can type this:

```
ModelState.Where(
  x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0
).Select(
  x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors }
)
```

into your Watch window.
This will collect all Keys generating error together with the error descritti in.

Comment: Brilliant - EXACTLY what I was looking for.  It combines "Key" and "Error" in such a way that I can check each model error by field name.  Perfect - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This linq query results in a list with all errormessages connected to its key.

```
var result2 = ModelState.SelectMany(m => m.Value.Errors.Select(s => new { m.Key, s.ErrorMessage }));
```