# Using ModelState.IsValid to Validate Login in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've got a small class:

```csharp
public class Login
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever someone tries to log in, this `Login` routine is called, but returns no information in the view if the `ModelState` is not valid:

```csharp
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login login)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

We have someone trying to log in using an email address that cannot get past our validator.

I tried adding some code to read the error messages and return those with this code, but the value `ModelState["Property"]` was `NULL` and caused a crash:

```csharp
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in ModelState["Property"].Errors) // <= Error on this line
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{item.Exception}: {item.ErrorMessage}");
    }

    ViewBag.ErrorValue = sb.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

For completeness, here is the `Login.cshtml` markup:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "ForgotPassword", "Dealer", null, null)
@if (ViewBag.ErrorValue != null)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
            <h2 class="text-danger">@ViewBag.ErrorValue</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I suspect there is something failing in the `[EmailAddress]` decorator for the `Login.Email` property, but I don't know what those rules are or how to report them to the person logging in.

How do I find the error and return an appropriate error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all Errors from ASP.Net MVC modelState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)

Comment: @derloopkat - it shows how to get the errors, but it doesn't tell me what the rules are for the class decoration `[EmailAddress]`. A Google search for "EmailAddress" pulls up too much noise.

Comment: You don't need to find the property nor using ViewBag. Either show ErrorSummary for all errors on the page or display one field error using the helper form the view (ValidationMessage, ValidationMessageFor, etc). It's plenty of examples out there.

Comment: hi maybe you want to return page with the errors instead of view

Answer (score 0):

The validation job is done by the rules you have defined for the form fields in the **Model** class defined for your **Razor** page. These rules are enforced by **JavaScript** files called **_ValidationScriptsPartial**. Those scripts include **Jquery, Unobtrusive and Validate**.
Make sure you have that file in your project and then add the following line exactly after the end of the **form** tag in your Razor page.

```
</form>
@section Scripts {
   @{
     await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Then instead of returning a view when the **ModelState** is not valid, try returning a page like below:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid == false){
   // This will display the errors in the span tags you have defined in the Razor page
  return Page();
}
```

Comment: Re *"Jquery"*: Not *"[jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)"*? E.g., is it literal?