# How to get the error message from model state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I'm using

```
modelstate.Adderror("test","test message")
```

And how can i get this modelstate value in controller itself.

Like I need to get the error message of "test" in the controller.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He asks for in the controller, I cannot verify this but I think this is simply something like:

```
ModelState["test"].Value
ModelState["test"].Error
ModelState["test"]
```

One of those above.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Test") %>`.