# How do I just put one error message on the screen with no summary in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to be able to provide a message on my screen that says 'The user name or password provided is incorrect'. So I have the following statement in my controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
```

And then on my view I have

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful.")
```

But that gives me the message:

> Login was unsuccessful
>
> - The user name or password provided is incorrect

So how do I just display one of these messages rather than both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the first text why not just use the other overload of the ValidationSummary method?

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Comment: this is okay but I still get an annoying bullet point on it, any idea how to just display the message?

Comment: I think the easiest is to just use css to remove the bullet style. Otherwise you could loop through the model state errors manually in your view. See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc