# ModelState.isValid error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have created an Edit Action method but it is not going inside ModelState.isValid. How can I check the error?

```
  public PartialViewResult UpdateAccountDetails(string accountNumber)
  {
      CreditReportService crService = new CreditReportService();

      AccountInfo account = new AccountInfo();
      account.Account = service.GetAccountDetails(accountNumber);
      account.AccountStatuses = service.GetAccountStatuses();
      account.AccountTypes = service.GetAccountTypes();
      account.CreditTerms = service.GetCreditTerms();

      return PartialView("_UpdateAccountDetails", account);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UpdateAccountDetails(Account account)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          service.SaveAccount(account);
          TempData["message"] = "Account has been updated successfully!";

          AccountInfo accountInfo = new AccountInfo();
          accountInfo.AccountStatuses = service.GetAccountStatuses();
          accountInfo.AccountTypes = service.GetAccountTypes();
          accountInfo.CreditTerms = service.GetCreditTerms();
          return PartialView("_UpdateAccountDetails", accountInfo);
      }
      else
      {
          return PartialView("_UpdateAccountDetails", account);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By accessing the [ModelState.Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors(v=VS.90).aspx) collection.  The collection contains a collection of [ModelError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470791(v=VS.90).aspx) items, which contain the error message and exception that was thrown to cause the model error.

---

**Edit:**
I guess I should have looked myself.  It seems that the controller's `ModelState` is actually a (dictionary) collection of `ModelState`'s.  To get all the errors, you should be able to get all instances of the `ModelError` classes via:

```
var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).ToList();
```

Comment: Updated, didn't realize the controller's ModelState was different.

Comment: ModelState doesnt have any Select method. I am getting error on select.

Comment: It's a `Linq` extension method.  Make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your code.

Comment: Better answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

```
var errors = var errors = ModelState.Where(m=>m.Value.Errors.Any()).Select(m => m.Value.Errors).ToList();
```

To only get a list of the errored fields only, rather than all fields and error list (exclude Errors length == 0).