# how to get ALL errors from viewdata.modelstate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do a bit of a custom error handler.  We have 4 tabs (using JQuery tabs), they are all build from one large model.  Say for simplicity the model looks like:

```
myModel.HomeInfo
myModel.PhoneNumbers
myModel.Addresses
myModel.PersonalDetails
```

Each part is an object that have various bits of information.  They all have attributes on them and validate messages.

At the top of the page (above the tabs) I want to display some top level errors, by that I mean the errors for attributes on the "myModel" object.  This works when I do the:

```
foreach (ModelState state in viewData.ModelState.Values)
```

When I do:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

on my view I get all errors from each of the four objects and all their children, (more than 10).  But when I go through the errors my self, (code above), I only get 2 errors, (the errors for "myModel" only, not its child properties).

I tried to use ILSPY to see what the validation summary is doing and replicate it.  Believe I had the code pretty much line for line, but it still only got the two errors.

I do not know what magic is going on when I use the @Html.ValidationSummary().

What I want to know is how I can get all the errors for the whole object my self to be able to display some of the errors on each tab.

for clarification here is my basic model:

```
public class MemberProfileModel
{
    [CompanyTabValid]
    public CompanyInformationModel CompanyInformation { get; set; }
    [ContactTabValid]
    public ContactInformationModel ContactInformation { get; set; }
    [InvoiceTabValid]
    public InvoiceInformationModel InvoiceInformation { get; set; }
    [TabProductIdentificationMarkValid]
    public ProductIdentificationMarkModel ProductIdentificationMark { get; set; }
 }

public class CompanyTabValid : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var model = value as CompanyInformationModel;
        if(model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        var failed = new ValidationResult("Company information incomplete.");

        return model.IsValid ? ValidationResult.Success : failed;
    }
}

public class ContactInformationModel : BaseModel
{
    public ContactInformationModel()
    {
        PrimarySiteAddress = new AddressInformation();
        PrimarySiteContact = new ContactInformation();
        RegisteredOfficeAddress = new AddressInformation();
        RegisteredOfficeContact = new ContactInformation();

    }
    public override void Validate()
    {
        IsValid = PrimarySiteAddress.IsValid &&
                  PrimarySiteContact.IsValid &&
                  RegisteredOfficeAddress.IsValid &&
                  RegisteredOfficeContact.IsValid;
    }
    public AddressInformation PrimarySiteAddress { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation PrimarySiteContact { get; set; }
    public AddressInformation RegisteredOfficeAddress { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation RegisteredOfficeContact { get; set; }

}

public class AddressInformation : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// This property is only here to make EF happy, do not use
    /// </summary>
    public int LocationTypeValue { get; set; }
    public LocationType LocationType { get { return (LocationType) LocationTypeValue; }  set { LocationTypeValue = (int) value;  } }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Address Line 1 required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1 *")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 3")]
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Town required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Town *")]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "County required.")]
    [Display(Name = "County *")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country *")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [RequiredOneOfTwo("InterationalPostCode", ErrorMessage="PostCode or international PostCode are required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Post Code *")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [RequiredOneOfTwo("PostCode", ErrorMessage = "International PostCode or PostCode are required.")]
    [Display(Name = "International Post Code *")]
    public string InterationalPostCode { get; set; }

    public override void Validate()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressLine1))
        {
            this.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Town))
        {
            this.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(County))
        {
            this.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
        {
            this.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostCode) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(InterationalPostCode))
        {
            this.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }

        this.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

I have shown an example of a validation attribute (some of ours are custom, some are normal), the top level MemberProfileModel = myModel in this example, and ContactInformationModel is one of its children which in turn has its own objects such as AddressInformation.

Thanks

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @emragins I have seen this one and a few others.  the modelstate dictionary only has two keys when I debug it.  I don't see the other 8+ objects / keys that the validationsummary will return

Comment: Not sure, then.  Using Chris McKenzie's code, I was able to get all my errors (from parent and numerous children) with no problems.  Maybe it's an mvc3-mvc4 thing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why this wasn't working for me.  As usual it was me being silly.  Because the model has multiple layers / levels to it, I.e. model.someobject.someotherobject.someproperty, when I called tryValidateModel it would validate the top level but not the inner layers.

The solution to this was to ensure they are all called:

```
            TryValidateModel(mp);
            TryValidateModel(mp.ContactInformation.PrimarySiteAddress);
            TryValidateModel(mp.ContactInformation.RegisteredOfficeAddress);
```

So my solution is to either create a method to call try validate on each object level or create a refelctive method to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the post event of your page, in the controller just add this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TestViewModel testViewModel)
{
// If not Valid
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return this.View(testViewModel)
}
...
}
```

And don't forget to add your required and/or other validation to your viewmodel access methods:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.MyProject), ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_Test")]
public virtual string HomeInfo { get; set; }
```

And in your view:

```
<div class="editor-row">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeInfo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeInfo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeInfo)
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I had already done with my model.  I am trying to get these errors on the GET rather than the post, (which the validationsummary seems happy to do but iterating the error explicitly doesn't return them).  I do not want to have to define every validation message property for various reasons, one its verbose, two I want them in an UL LI so valid ones would cause an empty LI

Comment: @Jon I didn't know that the ModelState has errors in the GET? Would a better interpretation of your question then be, "How can I get all of the potential error messages for my model?"  Or maybe your problem is trying to display them?  I am very confused now what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @emragins sorry, yes. I validate my model before the GET (user can save bad data to be able to fix it later).  I need to be able to get all the errors for that model programmitically.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

I got this from here:
http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/aspnet/Mvc/q/stackoverflow/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate

```
public static List<string> GetErrorListFromModelState
                                              (ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
      var query = from state in modelState.Values
                  from error in state.Errors
                  select error.ErrorMessage;

      var errorList = query.ToList();
      return errorList;
}
```