# ASP.NET MVC 3 / 4 ValidationMessageFor without html markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there are a way to utilize Html.ValidationMessageFor() to return the validation text without the HTML markup around it?

Currently this code:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

Returns this:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Model.SomeProperty" data-valmsg-replace="true">This field is required.</span>
```

And I would much prefer this:

```
This field is required.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: m0s's comment lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m0s's comment pointed me to this StackOverflow question/answer. ([How do I get the collection of Model State Errors in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc))

This is probably redundant but here is my working solution:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("SomeProperty))
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty), 
          new {
               @some_attribute = ViewData.ModelState["SomeProperty"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage })     
}
```

Obviously, you want to ensure your ModelState has errors before addressing the first one, in my case this will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    htmlHelper.ValidationMessage(string ModelName).  I think that returns the string without the markup.

Comment: Unfortunately that returns the same result.

Comment: Only other thing I can suggest is a custom template to display the error message and strip the unwanted html away inside the template.