# List is not binding to the model while posting the form to mvc action method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page in which I am maintaining a list as shown below.

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.RuleDetails.Rules.AssociatedRules.Count; i++)
 {
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="true" value="true" />
                   @Model.RuleDetails.Rules.AssociatedRules[i].Rule_Name 
            </label>
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RuleDetails.Rules.AssociatedRules[i].Rule_Id)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RuleDetails.Rules.AssociatedRules[i].State)
        </div>
  }
```

when I click on the save button I can see data going to the server in network monitor ..

[image]

but when I see the model in action parameter I am getting RuleDetails.Rules.AssociatedRules as null.

I investigated the HttpRequest Object in Controller and I can see my values in the request params

[image]

I don't know what is happening in the server and what I am missing . is there any way to control the model binding.

This is the model of the view

[image]

and Controller has only action methods which will basically fetch and save mode.

Comment: Refer `Prefer Binding Over Request.Form` in http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: Whats the code in the controller? And what is the viewmodel?

Comment: @user1666620 I have updated the question with model of the page.

Comment: do you have the actual code? what are the data types etc? Screenshots aren't much good, Nobody wants to have to type out a load of somebody else's code if they want to try to reproduce the problem. If it's prorietary, then obfuscate the code - just allow us the minimum amount to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: My first guess would be that the model is just not binding due to some type binding error. Check the `ModelState.IsValid` property, it's probably false and you will have an error in the model state values. See this answer for a quick example on reading the errors from the property. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22305555/426894

Comment: I can see ModelState.IsValid as true in the action method. @asawyer

Comment: Darn, well it was just a guess. Next suggestion is to download the debug symbols and step through the model binder until you find the issue.

Comment: @asawyer I end up writing my own model binder.. now it is working.

Comment: @SujithKp I'd write up what you did as an answer and accept it then.

Comment: @asawyer I have added the code as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the model binder that I wrote. I know this is not the solution that I was looking but I have already spent lot of time looking the cause of the issue. Will investigate in more detail after meeting the deadlines ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ModelBinderPoc
{
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private bool IsPropertyClrObject(PropertyInfo obj)
    {
        var type = obj.PropertyType;

        return (type.Equals(typeof(Boolean)) || type.Equals(typeof(string)) || type.Equals(typeof(Int32)) || type.Equals(typeof(decimal))
            || type.Equals(typeof(DateTime)) || type.Equals(typeof(DateTime?)));
    }

    private void SetClrObjectValue(PropertyInfo pinfo, object model, object pvalue)
    {
        pinfo.SetValue(model, pvalue, null);
    }

    private object CreateCollection(object obj, string propertyPart)
    {
        var propertyLength = propertyPart.IndexOf('[');
        var propertyName = propertyPart.Substring(0, propertyLength);
        var index = propertyPart.Substring(propertyLength + 1, propertyPart.Length - (propertyLength + 2));

        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            var ctype = property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if (ctype.FullName.Contains("System.Collections.Generic.IList"))
            {
                var gptype = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                var listInstance = (IList)typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(gptype).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
                property.SetValue(obj, listInstance, null);
                propertyValue = listInstance;
            }
        }

        int count = (int)propertyValue.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(propertyValue, null);
        var gtype = propertyValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
        object listItem = null;

        if (int.Parse(index) + 1 > count)
        {
            ((IList)propertyValue).Add(listItem = gtype.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null));
        }
        else
        {
            listItem = propertyValue.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item").Invoke(propertyValue, new object[] { int.Parse(index) });
        }

        return listItem;
    }


    private void setPropertyValue(object model, string propertyName, string value)
    {
        var objectValue = model;

        foreach (var propertyPart in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            var propertyLength = propertyPart.Length;

            if ((propertyLength = propertyPart.IndexOf('[')) != -1)
            {
                objectValue = CreateCollection(objectValue, propertyPart);
                continue;
            }

            var property = GetProperty(objectValue, propertyPart);

            if (property == null)
                return; // invalid property

            if (IsPropertyClrObject(property))
            {
                SetValue(objectValue, property, value);
                return;
            }

            var propertyValue = GetValueOf(objectValue, property);
            if (propertyValue == null)
            {
                var newObjValue = GetNewValueFor(property);
                SetObjValue(objectValue, property, newObjValue);
                propertyValue = newObjValue;
            }

            objectValue = propertyValue;
        }
    }

    private void SetValue(object obj, PropertyInfo pinfo, object value)
    {
        if (pinfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime?)))
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value as string, out date))
                pinfo.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            else
                pinfo.SetValue(obj, null, null);
            return;
        }

        if (value.ToString().Length != 0) 
            pinfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, pinfo.PropertyType), null);
    }

    private void SetObjValue(object obj, PropertyInfo pinfo, object value)
    {
        pinfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }

    private object GetValueOf(object obj, PropertyInfo pinfo)
    {
        return pinfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    private object GetNewValueFor(PropertyInfo pinfo)
    {
        return Instantiate(pinfo.PropertyType);
    }

    private object Instantiate(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null); ;
    }

    private PropertyInfo GetProperty(object obj, string property)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = Instantiate(bindingContext.ModelType);
        var parameters = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params;

        foreach (var key in parameters.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = parameters.GetValues(key);
            setPropertyValue(model, key, value.First());
        }

        return model;
    }
}
}`
```