# How can I access FluentValidation errors from within an api post method?

Tags: .net-core, fluentvalidation

In the [Fluent Validation docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet)
There is an example

```
    public class PeopleController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person) {

        if(! ModelState.IsValid) { // re-render the view when validation failed.
```

// How do I get the Validator error messages here?

```
            return View("Create", person);
        }

        TempData["notice"] = "Person successfully created";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
}


public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Where the validator has been set up as

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
    }
}
```

Suppose a validation fails.  How can I access the Validation Error from within the Create method?

I ask because I am using FluentValidation with an API and need a way for the API to communicate validation errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ModelState for errors ( True / False )

```
<% YourModel.ModelState.IsValid %>
```

Check for a specific Property error

```
<% YourModel.ModelState["Property"].Errors %>
```

Check for all errors

```
<% YourModel.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1) %>
```

There are a ton of good answers to this question on here.
Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573302/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-model-state-errors-in-asp-net-mvc) to one and here is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352948/how-to-get-all-errors-from-asp-net-mvc-modelstate)